# Loop through JSON data Associatively

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I loop through this json data without referring to the data items by a number. I would like to use it as an associative array. I have this so far:

```
$.post('/controlpanel/search', { type: type, string: string }, function(data){

        $.each(data, function() {

            $.each(this, function(index, itemData) {

                       //alert(data.id) something like this
                       //currently returns undefined

            });

        });

   }, 'json');
```

Example Json Code:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"","link":"http:\/\/www.msn.com","date_added":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"privacy_type":"0","user_id":"8","field2":"","field3":"","bookmark_id":"70","tag":"clean"}]
```

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your element is in the first level, `id` is available there via `this` (the current element), like this:

```
$.post('/controlpanel/search', { type: type, string: string }, function(data){
  $.each(data, function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
}, 'json');
```